# HTML5: Playing HTTP streaming on HTTPS domain

Tags: javascript, html, video, browser, https

Can I play HTTP streaming on HTTPS domain without browser's security errors? The browser blocks that requests by default.

I use hls.js library for .m3u8 desktop playing support. When I play content natively without it (via mobile or Mac's Safari), the browser shows warning but doesn't blocks requests. But when I play it on same devices with hls.js enabled, or via desktop browsers, the requests are blocked.

Comment: Why use a library if you do not need to?

Comment: by default desktop browsers don't support HLS. Excluding - Safari on Mac.

Comment: Why cannot you use the same protocol as existing `document`?

Comment: It will overload videoservers

Comment: @Psijic [are you sure](https://www.httpvshttps.com/)? Can you use a diffrent server for the videos but over https?

Comment: @programmer5000 hm, don't sure. It that's what our server's administrator says.

Comment: @Psijic remember, if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44392932/65607160) helped you, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark next to it.

Comment: @programmer5000 I really like your answer (which is why I upvoted), but at least give OP some time to respond. :)

Comment: Our test runs showed - processor's uploading was increased by 60-70% for HTTPS encryption and video output was dropped more than a half.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [You can't.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content)

Mixed content, when you have resources served over http on a https site, can be passive or active.

### Passive:

- Images
- Videos
- Audio

### Active:

- Javascript
- CSS
- iFrames
- Objects (flash, etc.)
- **XHR (requests made with javascript)**

The problem is that your video is fetched with hls.js, which is considered active content (see that last bullet), and therefore blocked.

However, if the browser fetches it through a `<video>` element, it is considered passive content and allowed.

### Suggestions / workarounds

- **Switch your video servers to HTTPS.** This is the preferred option. [HTTPS is *faster*](https://www.httpvshttps.com/). [You said that your server's administrator says that the HTTPS will "overload videoservers"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392426/html5-playing-http-streaming-on-https-domain#comment75785290_443924260). I doubt that. Try it out and see.

  > If you stop reading now you only need to remember one thing: SSL/TLS is not computationally expensive any more. -- Adam Langley (Google)
- Switch to a diffrent video format, like mp4 or ogg or [load both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25197196/6560716). Your website will load faster because you don't need a library.
- <s>Switch to http</s> **DON'T DO THIS**