# Adding video source for different video in css

Tags: html, css, video

I have a video in the video tag and I need to add another video for the responsiveness, but I don't want it to be set as a background. I am using bootstrap 4 carousel.

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="carousel-item active" >
 <video autoplay loop muted id="myVideo">
  <source src="videosource.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>  
</div>
```

Here is my CSS :

```
.carousel-item{
    height:100vh;
}
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: "I need to add another video for the responsiveness” can you elaborate. How is the video more so responsive that the element you display it with? Have you considered media queries?

Comment: @soulshined i need the video to fit both height and width so now the current video crops out the main character in small screens so i made another video to make this character visible. Yes i did try media queries but like i said i don't want the video to be set as background but if there any solution using media queries please suggest to me

Comment: I don't think this is solvable with only CSS if you can't set the background for whatever reason. The `video` tag [can take multiple sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698718/can-a-html-5-video-tag-have-multiple-mp4-sources-with-different-codecs), but unlike `srcset`/`sizes` on a picture element it doesn't have any way for the browser to pick the best one depending on the device scale.

Comment: @Fdebijl Thank you, actually i found a way to do what i needed with css without adding another video source i used negative values for margins with media queries to crop out the unneeded areas in my video, allowing me to focus on my main character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - *"I need to add another video for the responsiveness"*
> - *"Because when the current video is viewed from mobile or template the main character is cropped out"*

You could try resizing the video to always fit on screen.

Does something like the example code below help you to think of a new solution? Make it as new HTML page and then test the desktop window resizing and also test on mobile.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style> .full-height-test { height: 95vh;} </style>

<body>

<div class="carousel-item active"  >
    <video  controls autoplay muted id="myVideo" class="full-height-test" >
    <source src="videosource.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you this is helpful but not with all screen sizes but it give me an idea to manually crop the unneeded areas in my video using negative margin values and media queries also now that i got a new idea and is to set height for each group of screen sizes using this solution